# If $x$ and $y$ are two vectors in Hilbert Space $X$ such that $||x||=||y||=1$ then $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $x$ and $y$ are two vectors in a Hilbert Space $X$ such that $\lVert x\rVert=\lVert y\rVert=1$ then $\left<x+y,x-y\right>=0$

Proof:

$$\begin{align}
\langle x+y,x-y\rangle&=\langle x,x\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle-\langle y,y\rangle\\
&=\Vert x\Vert^2-\langle x,y\rangle+\color{red}{\underbrace{\langle x,y\rangle}_?}-\Vert y\Vert^2\\
&=1-1\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

My question is why did $\langle y,x\rangle$ change to $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Isn't $\langle y,x\rangle$ equal to $\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$?

Comment: Somewhere in the book they must have specified that they are working with **real** Hilbert spaces, where $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ is "symmetric and $\Bbb R$-bilinear", instead of "hermitian and $\Bbb C$-sesquilinear".

Comment: In the hermitian case, $X=\Bbb C$, $x=1$, $y=i$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct. Somewhere, they should have specified that you deal with real Hilbert spaces, otherwise the book is wrong, as this argument obviously only holds for real Hilbert spaces.

The statement itself is even wrong in the complex case, as shown by Hagen von Eitzen in the comments.